# .innerHTML does not work on Windows Phone browser

Tags: innerhtml

I have a problem with a label field on my HTML page. I have set a label as below:

```
<label id="labelid" class="required control-label">Old Label Value</label>
```

Based on some other form input, I am trying to change the value of the label using javascript. The code for that is:

```
function change()
{
    document.getElementById(labelid).innerHTML = "New Label Value";
}
```

For some reason, this works fine on a desktop browser. It also works fine on IOS and Android phones. But when i view this HTML page on a windows phone browser, the new value is not visible.

Please advise. I must be doing something silly, but i cant figure it out.

The basic objective is to update a label based on what the user has typed in a text field. Please let me know if there is another way of doing it instead of using labels.

Comment: Have you determined whether `change()` is actually triggered in the phone's browser?

Comment: You should keep labelid in either in single quote or in double quote.

Comment: How are you binding the event that triggers `change()`?

Comment: @PM77-1 The change() function does trigger on the phone browser as well. I am calling change() on the blur event on a text field. Something like this: 

<input type="text" onblur='change()'>

Comment: As you have already answered this question, please forgive me for asking it again.  How do you know that `change()` is actually called?  Did you see it in the debugger? Or, may be, you put some console logging inside the function? Please clarify.

Comment: @PM77-1 Well i put an "alert" on the first line of change() function. The alert message is called on the phone browser too. So i guess the change() function is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You didn't have quotes around labelid..

```
function change() {

 document.getElementById("labelid").innerHTML = "New Label Value"; 

}
```

Comment: I tried single and double quotes around the labelid. But it does not work. The issue is with the phone browser because it works fine on the desktop browser.

Comment: JS allows single and double quotes almost interchangeably.

Comment: Just tested placing the above code with your div in a simple html file and testing in Chrome for android worked for me. How are you testing?

Comment: @user2941841 Sorry, i had updated my original post with some details.  It works fine on IOS and Android phones. But when i view this HTML page on a windows phone browser, the new value is not visible. I am testing by hosting the HTML page on an azure website and i viewing the HTML page on the actual phones.

Comment: Are you using a html viewer or actual wrh browser in the windows phone? When I tested on my android device the html viewer didnt work but when i viewed it in the chrome browser it worked

Comment: @user2941841 I am using the browser on the windows phone. I guess i will switch to a readonly text field instead of a label as i am not getting any solution.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to Windows phone browser, Mark Chamberlain had these comments to a similar issue:

"Standard Javascript injection is not enabled; most likely due to risk of attacks, web site spoofing etc. If you need to customize a web site that you own, you should implement your changes on the web site (server) side."

This could possibly extend to adding/deleting/modifying HTML is my interpretation.

From this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/94d4a806-3eca-411e-adda-9e0fa8a6f467/how-to-inject-or-insert-the-javascript-code-in-webbrowser-windows-phone-7?forum=wpdevelop